# Adjective for consensus

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective that indicates something was reached by consensus? "Consensual" seems to be a synonym of "consentual" and have nothing to do with consensus. Online dictionaries listing "consensus" do not include any reference to adjective forms.

Example:

> Most of the committee agreed it was a good idea, and the rest didn't oppose it. The decision was ____

I am not looking for "unanimous", since to my understanding consensus is about overall agreement even if some individuals disagree, whereas unanimity is a lot stronger. For instance, you almost never hear claims about "unanimity among experts/scientist" on some issue, only consensus.

Comment: How about _united_, _same_, _consistent_ or _undivided_?

Comment: The committee was united, not the decision. Same as what, consistent with what? I don't think any of these fit my example sentence. Undivided might fit (though awkwardly). But it (and united) really seem more like replacements for unanimous, not "consensus-al". Again, consensus leaves room for individual disagreement as long as the whole body is in agreement: consensus could be reached after many debates and compromises to placate the opposition. You'd hardly call that "united".

Comment: It would be "consensual". As far as I know it (also) means what you want here. What makes you think otherwise ? It certainly is often used in that sense in mainstream newspapers.

Comment: You say *"Consensual" seems to be a synonym of "consentual" and have nothing to do with consensus*, yet the etymology of the word is **directly** from "consensus". If you insist on rejecting *consensual* as the (obvious) answer, you need to [edit] your question to include a definition of *consensual* from a reputable dictionary to support your contention.

Comment: consensus-based

Answer (score 2):

The noun "consensus" is often used as a modifier to refer to the decision that was reached via that process. So you can say:

> It was a consensus decision.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/consensus):

> [as modifier] ‘a consensus view’

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct, "consensual" is more about "with a person's consent", rather than a group decision.

Its not a single word but: "general agreement" implies that, of the unspecified number of individuals involved, most agreed to the decision; it leaves room for some of those involved to have disagreed, but suggests that the ultimate decision was agreed by a majority...

Answer (score 0):

> **consentaneous**
>
> Done or made by general consent; widely agreed or approved.

[[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-adjective-for/consensus.html)]

and from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consentaneous) (thanks due to Joachim):

> **consentaneous**
>
> 1. expressing agreement : SUITED
> 2. done or made by the consent of all

However, @WS2 adds a warning note that OED's latest example is from as far back as 1873, and the Google 1-gram echoes the implication that this word is at best archaic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: WordHippo is really not an authoritative resource, but [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consentaneous)'s a Merriam-Webster link. Note that Lexico doesn't list the word.

Comment: @Joachim Yes. This is the correct answer and is confirmed by the Oxford English Dictionary - though they do not have an example of its use more recent than 1873.

Answer (score -1):

As a *group*, the decision was agreed upon. Although some members may not have voted for it, or may even have voted against it, meaning it wasn't *unanimous*, as a *process* the decision followed the rules and procedures of requiring a majority view.

Therefore, the *group* decision was [**concordant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concordant):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> CONSONANT, AGREEING
>
> // All three tests have *concordant* results.
> // the movie's opening-weekend gross was fairly *concordant* with box-office returns for that genre

---

The difficulty is one of semantics and context. When a group decision is made, some people may not agree with the specific decision itself, but they may still agree with the fact that it was reached by following a process that they agree with.

In other words, from the viewpoint of an individual dissenter:

> We will have to agree to disagree.
> I don't believe what you say, but I will defend your right to say it.
> I support and respect the process and the decision—even if it's not the result I wanted.

It's a matter of perspective.

The decision itself was *accepted* because it was in *concord* with (in agreement with or consonant with) the majority opinion.

Comment: I don't think "concordant" works. It's used to say that one thing agrees with some other thing, not that the thing was produced by agreement.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's exactly how I see it. The decision was not disputed. It followed the accepted procedures. They all agreed to *abide* by it. I can't think of any other way of expressing it when the specific decision itself is not unanimous.